# read file and based on criterion print desire output

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, printf

I have input file which looks like this:

```
H1
O1
C1
H2
H3
O2
C2
Br1
```

I want to have an output file which to have the following output

```
H1 = 1
O1 = 8
C1 = 6
H2 = 1
H3 = 1
O2 = 8
C2 = 6
Br1 = 35
```

So when hydrogen is present I want to be equal to 1 (equivalent to 1 electron) and consequently when carbon to be equal to 6, when oxygen to be equal to 8 and when bromine to be equal to 35.

Comment: can you be more clear, like what is the input and expected output

Comment: the input file has the following format in a column                                           H1
O1
C1
H2
H3
O2
C2
Br1 and the desire output should have the following format in column H1 = 1
O1 = 8
C1 = 6
H2 = 1
H3 = 1
O2 = 6
C2 = 8
Br1 = 35 I do not mind whether using bash scripting or any other programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[0-9]' '
    BEGIN{
        x["H"]=1;
        x["O"]=8;
        x["C"]=6;
        x["Br"]=35;
    }
    { print $0" = "x[$1]; }
' input_file > output_file
```

Output:

```
H1 = 1
O1 = 8
C1 = 6
H2 = 1
H3 = 1
O2 = 8
C2 = 6
Br1 = 35
```

Comment: this is awesome!

Comment: although the idea works fine in the output file first prints the H1 and then in the second line gives  = 1 then in the third line only again prints the O1 and then in the third line prints = 8. I tried {printf "%7s\n", $0} but without success

Comment: I don't understand why but with print $0" = "x[$1]; adds a tab between column 1 and column 2

Comment: even I separated column 1 (the one having the H1 O1 C1) into a file 1 and a column 2 (with the electron numbers 1 8 6) in a file 2 and then I did paste -d ' ' file 1 file 2 > file 3 and I still get a tab between the 2 columns

Comment: is there any way I can send you my input file because I honestly do not know what else to try

Comment: thanks all!! my input file had corrupt format, everything works just fine now!!! many many thanks again

Comment: glad to hear that. We should clean up the comments then, as it won't help fellow readers. And if my answer worked for you, you might consider accepting it by clicking the check mark on the left side :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the file `input` containing the values you specified :

```
for tuple in 'H1,1' 'O1,8' 'C1,6' 'H2,1' 'H3,1' 'O2,6' 'C2,8' 'Br1,35'; do
    search=$(echo "$tuple" | cut -d',' -f1)
    replace=$(echo "$tuple" | cut -d',' -f2)
    sed -i "s/$search/$search = $replace/g" input
done
```

Comment: thanks I really appreciate your reply! however in the case of having in the input file more than 200 rows of the sequence in column H1 O1 C1 H2 O2 C2 ..... H100 O100 C100 is there a nicer way to set a criterion? for example if the first character is C then print out C = 6

Comment: @Dimitris Mintis : if there are more values to match, the tuples may be specified in an extra file rather than inline. If you'd prefer to match on the first character only, it's also possible (with regular expressions) since the search/replacement is performed by `sed`. To know more, I guess you'd have to edit your question or open a new one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Done by sed command and it worked fine too

command

```
sed -i  -e "/H/s/.*/& = 1/" -e "/O/s/.*/& = 8/" -e "/C/s/.*/& = 6/" -e "/Br/s/.*/& = 35/" filename
```

output

```
H1 = 1
O1 = 8
C1 = 6
H2 = 1
H3 = 1
O2 = 8
C2 = 6
Br1 = 35
```